# Analysis for sample at different times

Tags: panel-data

I have a sample of individuals who migrated from Texas. They are all measured at time 0, within different census tracts. I am interested in seeing how their tract level conditions changed (based on, let's say, variable j) through their move. The individuals are not all measured at the times time 2, but are observed one to two times between years 1 and 10 (which may or may not be the same as the year they moved). What are some good approaches to use to measure how variable j changed based on their move?